# Meteor - sorting (current user is always put at the top of list )

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

I want to sort the list of users ( by name ) in my app. When I login with any user then that user is put at the top of list.

Example, I have data as below:

```
[
    {name: "phat 1"},
    {name: "phat 3"},
    {name: "phat 2"}
]
```

When I login with "phat 3", and performt sort, the result:

```
[
    {name: "phat 3"},
    {name: "phat 1"},
    {name: "phat 2"}
]
```

When I login with "phat 2", and performt sort, the result:

```
[
    {name: "phat 2"},
    {name: "phat 1"},
    {name: "phat 3"}
]
```

This is my code:

```
// server
Meteor.publish('users', function (options: Options) {
    return Users.find({}, options);
});
// Client
const options: any = {
    sort: { 'name': 1}
};
MeteorObservable.subscribe('users', options).subscribe(() => {
    let data = Users.find({}).fetch();
});
```

Someone help me,
Thanks so much!

Comment: you need to sort in the client side as well. sorting in publication is not enough.

Comment: But, How do we search with multiple conditions and combine with search , paging ....

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question... As it is too broad at the moment. Explain what exactly you're trying to achieve and what you tried/did so far by editing your question.

Comment: when I use skip and limit to paging the list of users. (http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find)

The current user always appear at the top of results. It mean when I login with username is "myname". the results contains user with "myname" for all page

Comment: Meteor.users.find({_id: {$ne: Meteor.userId()}},{your sort/limit here})

Comment: Actually no, that will leave out the current user. Your client side find() query should also have the sort/limits as I said initially

Comment: Hi @Luna, I have used this way, but it does not work :(

Comment: do you want to show the current user at top all the time, or the opposite?

Comment: I think cause I use autorun to synchronous data `MeteorObservable.subscribe('users', options, searchText).subscribe(() => { MeteorObservable.autorun().zone().subscribe(); })`

Comment: Hi @Luna, I use { $ne: Meteor.userId() } on both service and client, It work well, Thanks for supporting :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading this question as "I'd like to display a list of users sorted by name but always place the current user at the top.

I had exactly this issue and solved it in a very simple way that avoids any array manipulations (I'll illustrate with blaze):

html:

```
<template name="userList">
{{#with currentUser}}
  {{name}}
{{/with}}
{{#each otherUsers}}
  {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

js:

```
Template.userList.helpers({
  currentUser(){ return Meteor.user() },
  otherUsers(){
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }},{ sort: { name: 1 }});
  }
});
```

If the layout for each user is complicated then it's easy to use a nested template for displaying each user.

Comment: Hi @Michel Floyd, This way dose not work, I think cause I use autorun to synchronous data
`MeteorObservable.subscribe('users', options, searchText).subscribe(() => {
     MeteorObservable.autorun().zone().subscribe();
})`

Comment: It will work after the data is ready, you can `{{#if}}` the whole template to wait for data.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort it by Your current logged id,

```
Users.find().fetch().sort(function(a, b){
    return b._id == Meteor.userId();
});
```

Comment: In my example only sort by name, but in fact, I want to sort by something and more .... Thanks anyway

Comment: `phat 3` it's a name in Users collection?

Comment: yes, It is combined with 'meteor/accounts-base'; and this is my collection

Comment: export const Users = MongoObservable.fromExisting(Meteor.users);